# Send Object created from MainActivity to Fragments TabbedView

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, bluetooth

In my App i start with TabbedView that have MainActivity with container that show 3 Fragments for each time (depend what user select).

The MainActivity.java start a Bluetooth comunication with OBD car and request commands until the app in on.
Now, when the OBD respond in my MainActivity i had an Handler that take the response and with setter() method put this method inside a class PidsCommand.java.

After that i would take this Object that contain all updated data to the Fragment that show that data in real time.
So i need to pass this object when the DashboardFragment is created and showed...

There is some best way to do that? I'm in the right way?
And how can i share that Object created in the MainActivity to the Fragment so i can take data with getter() method and popolate the view with that data?

**EDIT**

As i can see i only need to pass the object when i create a newInstace of Fragment... don't need the interface because i need to send the object when i create the Fragment for read it and show data.

This is the istance of Framgent:

```
 public static DashboardFragment newInstance(OBDPids pids) {
        DashboardFragment dashboardfragment = new DashboardFragment();

        Bundle argsPids = new Bundle();
        argsPids.putBundle("pids", pids);
        dashboardfragment.setArguments(argsPids);

        return dashboardfragment;
    }
```

But putBundle and putParcable are good good.... how can i pass my obect with Instance?

And in the Fragment i take data back with:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);

    Bundle args = getArguments();
    OBDPids pids = args.getParcelable("pids");

    return view;
}
```

Or is not a good way for do that?

**EDIT 2**

This solution can be good instead of interface?

In the MainActivity.java

```
pids = new OBDPids();
public OBDPids getMyObject() {
        return pids;
    }
```

In the Fragment

```
OBDPids myObjectFromActivity = null;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);

        MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
        myObjectFromActivity = activity.getMyObject();
return view;
}
```

Comment: Take a look: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: I need the comunication in other way Activity to Fragment.
If i understand the interface let me to comunicate to Fragment back to Activity.

I need to send Object to Fragment from Activity

Comment: post edited for more information